# Python string concatenation on series with ternary condition operator

Tags: python, string, pandas, concatenation, series

I want to add a column that should represent a URL to a Pandas dataframe based on concatenation of other columns. Additionally I would like to add a condition.

Currently, it looks like this

```
matches['url'] = 'http://www.example.org' +
                matches['column1'] + 
                '/' +
                (matches['id'].str[-3:] if matches['id'].str.contains('M|-0') else matches['id'].str[-4:]) +
                '/xyz.pdf'
```

The condition where I have problems is this one: `(matches['id'].str[-3:] if matches['id'].str.contains('M|-0') else matches['id'].str[-4:])`

This should do the following: if `matches['id']` contains either the string `M` or `-0` then `matches['id'].str[-3:]` should happen (that is, take the last 3 characters of the `matches['id']` column, else `matches['id'].str[-4:]` should happen.

However, I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I am aware that I could create an intermediate column with `apply()` and encoding the condition in there. But I would like to do it with a nice one-liner and I think I am not too far away from the solution. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you should construct the parts of string as variables before creating the string. And when creating the string, use `.format()`.

Comment: You can't do it that way because the ternary operator isn't vectorized.  It is doing the if-then on the entire series at once, not on each individual element.  You'll have to build up the pieces of the string individually using `.map` or `.apply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) what perfectly works with `Series`:

```
mask = matches['id'].str.contains('M|-0') 
matches['url'] = 'http://www.example.org' + matches['column1'] + '/' +
                  np.where(mask, matches['id'].str[-3:], matches['id'].str[-4:]) + '/xyz.pdf'
```

Sample:

```
matches = pd.DataFrame({'id':['2010-M012','2010-1234','2010-1234'],
                        'column1':['s','d','m']})
print (matches)                 
  column1         id
0       s  2010-M012
1       d  2010-1234
2       m  2010-1234

mask = matches['id'].str.contains('M|-0') 
matches['url'] = 'http://www.example.org' + matches['column1'] + '/' + \
                  np.where(mask, matches['id'].str[-3:], matches['id'].str[-4:]) + '/xyz.pdf'

matches['url1'] = 'http://www.example.org' + matches['column1'] + '/' + \
                   matches['id'].map(lambda x : x[-3:] if (('M' in x) or ('-0' in x)) else x[-4:]) + '/xyz.pdf'

matches['url2'] = matches.apply(lambda x: 'http://www.example.org{}/{}/xyz.pdf'.format(x['column1'], x['id'][-3:] if (('M' in x['id']) or ('-0' in x['id'])) else x['id'][-4:]), axis=1)


print (matches)
  column1         id                                   url  \
0       s  2010-M012   http://www.example.orgs/012/xyz.pdf   
1       d  2010-1234  http://www.example.orgd/1234/xyz.pdf   
2       m  2010-1234  http://www.example.orgm/1234/xyz.pdf   

                                   url1                                  url2  
0   http://www.example.orgs/012/xyz.pdf   http://www.example.orgs/012/xyz.pdf  
1  http://www.example.orgd/1234/xyz.pdf  http://www.example.orgd/1234/xyz.pdf  
2  http://www.example.orgm/1234/xyz.pdf  http://www.example.orgm/1234/xyz.pdf
```

**Timings**:

```
matches = pd.DataFrame({'id':['2010-M012','2010-1234','2010-1234'],
                        'column1':['s','d','m']})
#[30000 rows x 2 columns]
matches = pd.concat([matches]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [168]: %timeit matches['url'] = 'http://www.example.org' + matches['column1'] + '/' + np.where(matches['id'].str.contains('M|-0'), matches['id'].str[-3:], matches['id'].str[-4:]) + '/xyz.pdf'
10 loops, best of 3: 50.9 ms per loop

In [169]: %timeit matches['url1'] = 'http://www.example.org' + matches['column1'] + '/' + matches['id'].map(lambda x : x[-3:] if (('M' in x) or ('-0' in x)) else x[-4:]) + '/xyz.pdf'
10 loops, best of 3: 22.1 ms per loop

In [170]: %timeit matches['url2'] = matches.apply(lambda x: 'http://www.example.org{}/{}/xyz.pdf'.format(x['column1'], x['id'][-3:] if (('M' in x['id']) or ('-0' in x['id'])) else x['id'][-4:]), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.07 s per loop
```

Comment: the `map()` approach works nice. thank you very much. interestingly the `np.where()` does not work. I do it exactly as you do. I do not get an exception, but the string matching (`str.contains()`) doesn't seem to work. do you know why this could be?

Comment: Hard question without data. Mask return correct `True` and `False` values?

Comment: Maybe need `mask = matches['id'].str.contains('^M|^-0')` for match start of string.

Comment: actually my strings look like this `2010-M012` (match) or `2010-1234` (no match). but i just found that `map()` does not work for me either.. it always matches the strings, even though `M` or `-0` does not appear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - unfortunately it does not works with my sample

Comment: Hrm, has Pandas overloaded `__radd__` and `__add__` on dataframes then perhaps.

Comment: @jezrael: it works, my string matching logic was wrong. I now realized that I need an additional or. but it seems to ignore it. my condition is now: `(lambda x : x[-3:] if ('-M' or '-0' in x) or (len(x)==8) else x[-4:])`, but it seems that the `len(x)==8` is ignored. is my syntax correct?

Comment: I alos change answer, also add or ;)

Comment: @beta - do you need `or (len(x)==8)` or `and (len(x)==8)` ?

Comment: ah fine. that was a pain in the ass for me :D didn't get the logic right. thanks.

Comment: i still dont know why `('-M' or '-0' in x) or (len(x)==8)` matches for this string `2016-6116` ?

Comment: @beta - for me it return string, what is converted to `True` - `x = '2016-6116'
a = ('-M' or '-0' in x) or (len(x)==8)
print (a)`

Comment: it think instead of `'-M' or '-0' in test` it has to be `'-M' in test or '-0' in test`. this was the mistake.

Comment: do you know, which one of your approaches (url1, url2, url3) is the fastest?

Comment: Hard question, but I can test it.

Comment: @beta - map solution win, check timings.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
(matches['id'].str[-3:] if matches['id'].str.contains('M|-0') else matches['id'].str[-4:])
```

to:

```
np.where(matches['id'].str.contains('M|-0'), matches['id'].str[-3:],matches['id'].str[-4:])
```

to see if it works.